# How can the start up log of Spacemac be viewed?

Tags: spacemacs, start-up

When I start Spacemacs there is a message about some faults on my setup which scroll past quickly before I can view them.

Is there some file or some buffer that holds them for review?

Comment: Notice that like many/most things, this is actually not specific to Spacemacs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to see it in `*Messages*` buffer.

You can use `SPC w p m` (Spacemacs specific) or `C-x 4 b` to visit that buffer in another window (or `C-x b` to visit it in the same window).  (When prompted for the buffer name completion is available: `*Me TAB`.)