# How to see *Messages* buffer in Spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, debugging

How to see `*Messages*` buffer as advised in this answer - https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/32069/23367?

---

**Why do I need this?**

I am new to Spacemacs and I am trying to understand how it can help me writing Ansible roles and testing them. I found [Ansible layer](http://spacemacs.org/layers/+tools/ansible/README.html), added `ansible` to `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` and restarted Spacemacs. Still I have no idea how to use that. `SPC m h a` doesn't work - resulting in [`SPC m is undefined`](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/6700). Spacemacs shows `/YAML\` at the bottom near the filename. I don't see that Spacemacs detected YAML file as an Ansible playbook - I don't get any hints or errors displayed on the screen. Perhaps I need to change mode from YAML to Ansible somehow, but first I need to check if there are any errors why loading the layer for Ansible.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 I tried `evil-tutor`, but didn't get far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible in Spacemacs with `SPC w p m` key sequence ([mentioned here](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/4259)).

For more general way, in Spacemacs you can open buffer list with <kbd>SPC b b</kbd>. Then you can use your arrow key to find the desired buffer.

[image: default buffer list]

If you don't find the desired one, probably it's hidden. Spacemacs use `Helm` and Helm hide 'unuseful' buffer by default. You can use <kbd>C-c a</kbd> to  `show hidden buffers`

Comment: Well, I can see messages, but when I try to close the window with `:q`, Spacemacs exits. But I found that `SPC w p m` works. https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/4259

Answer (score 7):

It's just a buffer, so any of the numerous methods of switching to a buffer can be used.

For example, using standard Emacs key sequences:

- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> `*Messages*` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-b</kbd> and select `*Messages*`
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `ibuffer` <kbd>RET</kbd> and select `*Messages*`
- <kbd><C-down-mouse-1></kbd> and select `*Messages*`
- Click on the `Buffers` menu, and select `*Messages*`
- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd><right></kbd> until you reach `*Messages*`

As it happens, there are also two key bindings specifically for this purpose:

- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> runs the command `view-echo-area-messages`
- Click `mouse-1` in the echo area (same space as the minibuffer).

So you would probably use one of those by preference; but I wanted to make it clear that there's nothing *special* about this buffer when it comes to viewing it -- you can reach it in the same ways you use to get to any other buffer.

Comment: I am always a bit wary when they add a tag like `[spacemacs]` or `[ergomacs]`. Sometimes they rebind stuff in those configs. (That is the reason why I did not write an answer for this one.) Have you tested whether it works in `spacemacs`?

Comment: No; I always leave it up to the user to translate from the standard keys to their own custom key bindings.  They can always run `emacs -Q` and check which command a standard key sequence is bound to, and then look up the equivalent in their own config.  I've edited the answer to clarify that I'm showing default Emacs bindings.

Comment: No doubt someone who uses spacemacs will provide a more targeted answer, if the suggestions I've made don't work.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I wonder if we shouldn't either (1) change the question to be about any buffer, not `*Messages*` or (2) delete it as a duplicate, and change the other question to be specifically about `*Messages*` (not Spacemacs log). I added a mention of how to get to `*Messages*` to the answer of the other question this one duplicates.

Comment: I added `mouse-1` click in echo area.

Comment: Thanks for that addition, @Drew.  I think there are sufficient other answers about "how to switch buffers" generally, and I don't think this answer is any more helpful in that regard, so I would keep this one about `*Messages*`.  I also found https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/29826 when looking for duplicates, but concluded that the two questions were slightly different, and warranted slightly different answers.  I think the same applies to the question the OP linked to -- similar as they are, it still feels ok to me for them to remain separate, as the motivations aren't quite the same.

Comment: <kbd>C-x</kbd> <key>b</key> then selecting worked. New window opens instead of current, but when I quit the window with `:q` the editor quits and previous window is not restored. With <key>C-x</key> <key>C-b</key> selection doesn't work. I guess focus is wrong. <key>M-x</key> `ibuffer` works, but also kills previous window. <key>C-x</key> <key>Right</key> didn't work for *Messages*. <key>C-h</key> <key>e</key> works! Still have to click to change the focus and scroll/close the window,