# How to use Ansible layer in Spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs

How to use [Ansible layer](http://spacemacs.org/layers/+tools/ansible/README.html) in Spacemacs?

---

I am trying to understand how to write Ansible roles and test them using this layer. I added `ansible` to `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers`, restarted Spacemacs and [checked *Messages*](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/50284/how-to-see-messages-buffer-in-spacemacs) to see what is loaded.

```
Loading /home/anatoli/.emacs.d/layers/+tools/ansible/packages.el (source)...done
Loading /home/anatoli/.emacs.d/layers/+tools/ansible/layers.el (source)...
Loading /home/anatoli/.emacs.d/layers/+lang/yaml/packages.el (source)...done
Loading /home/anatoli/.emacs.d/layers/+tools/ansible/layers.el (source)...done
...
Loading /home/anatoli/.emacs.d/layers/+tools/ansible/funcs.el (source)...done
...
Loading /home/anatoli/.emacs.d/layers/+tools/ansible/config.el (source)...done
```

I still don't see anything. `SPC m h a` from documentation doesn't work - resulting in [`SPC m is undefined`](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/6700). Spacemacs shows `/YAML\` at the bottom near the filename. I don't see that Spacemacs detected YAML file as an Ansible playbook - I don't get any hints or errors displayed on the screen. Perhaps I need to change mode from YAML to Ansible somehow. If so - how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Ansible layer to take action, your buffer filename must match one of `main.yml`, `site.yml`, `roles/.+\.yml`, `group_vars/.+`, *etc.* See the regex at the bottom of [ansible/config.el](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/v0.200.13/layers/+tools/ansible/config.el#L22) (`v0.200.13`) for exact patterns.

**EDIT:** I added some additional paths to the regex above in [PR #12726](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/pull/12726), which will go into Spacemacs `v0.300.x`.

In Emacs, you can manually enable `ansible-doc-mode` for the current buffer with `M-x ansible-doc-mode RET`. You'd probably also want to enable the company back-end with `M-: (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-ansible) RET`. Then use `M-x ansible RET` to toggle the Ansible minor mode, which provides syntax highlighting, completion, vault functions, etc.

Unfortunately, it's not a slam dunk to use Emacs *file variables* to enable this minor mode explicitly (for files that don't match the regex linked above); this is a separate conversation. See [Specifying File Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html) in the Emacs manual for more information. I use the following at the bottom of my files:

```
# Local Variables:
# eval: (ansible-doc-mode 1)
# eval: (add-to-list (quote company-backends) (quote company-ansible))
# eval: (ansible 1)
# End:
```

( P.S. Regarding your comment about *testing* Ansible roles with this Spacemacs layer, I don't think that is directly supported as a feature, but you could likely find ways to run test-kitchen or similar from Emacs. )